# ZTE MC888 5g modem port forwarding not working as expected

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, modem

Maybe someone has experience with ZTE mc888 5g modem, I've been trying to port forward so I could play with my friend on my Minecraft server but it doesn't seem to work at all and I'm confused why because I used to have Huawei 4G modem and it worked just fine.

I have done everything in Windows firewall and on my modem but nothing is working, if anyone has any clue how to fix it?

[image: modem port forwarding settings]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If it port forwarding does not seem to work and you have ruled everything out the simplest explanation is that your behind a CGNAT which wouldn’t be unheard of with a 5G modem.

Comment: Is the image of port-forwarding setup of the router? What do the two ipaddresses correspond to?